# MIPS error - find a maximum in an array

Tags: max, mips, spim

I want to write a program which finds the maximum value in an array.
When I try to start my programm I get the error "Exception occurred at PC=0x0040004c". I have no idea what this means and I have no idea whats wrong with my code.

```
 .data
 liste: .word 1, 2 ,3 ,41, 5, 6, 7

.text
main:
    la $a0 liste        #adresse des ersten Elements in $a0 gespeichert
    la $a1 28($a0)      #adresse des letzten Elements in $a1 gespeichert
    li $v0 0            #speichere 0 in v0

tester:
    beq $a0 $a1 exit    #test, if we are at the end of the array
    j findmax

findmax:
    la $t0 ($a0)        #copy a0 in t0
speichermax:
    la $v0 ($t0)        #adress of t0 (Maximum) in v0
    lw $v1 ($v0)        #value of the max in v1 

loop:   
    la $t0 4($t0)       #go to the next field content
    beq $v0 $a1 exit    #end of field is reached
    lw $t1 ($t0)

    sub $t1 $t1 $v1         # t1 = t1 - v1
    bgtz $t1 speichermax        
    #bgt $t1 $v1 speichermax    #test if t1>v1 -> yes: save the new max  in v1 (über speichermax)
    j loop

exit:
    lw $a0 ($t0) #print the maximum
    li $v0 1
    syscall

    li $v0 10 #exit
    syscall
```

Comment: An exception occurred at the instruction at address 0x0040004c. It's easy to see in the simulator which instruction that address corresponds to. So then you need to figure out why that instruction is causing an exception. Maybe you're trying to access an invalid memory address. If you can't figure out the reason just by looking at the code, then use the simulator's single-stepping feature to step through your code instruction by instruction, and check the values of all relevant registers and memory locations as you go along.

Answer (score 0):

Skipping the rest of the program I believe that this: `la $a1, 28($a0)`
 is wrong. Try this: `addi $s1, $a0, 28`.